# VS Code Typescript auto-completes foo.forEach() to foo.array.forEach()

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the tslint plugin and auto-completion always adds `array` before `forEach()`.

I couldn't find if there was a difference between the two notations
`foo.array.forEach()` and `foo.forEach()` (foo is already an array here). Has anyone got any idea about this?

Comment: Could you post what `foo` is ? Unless `foo` has a field named `array` there is no reason for the IDE to suggest adding `array`

Comment: Probably worth mentioning what IDE you're using too.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I'm using vs code. But the auto completion comes from a plugin called tslint.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Foo's value doesn't matter here, it could be anything, but always an array. Thank you for the clarification, this is what I expected.

Comment: Well, there is a major difference: one compiles and runs, and the other doesn't. tslint doesn't do any auto-completion. It signals linting errors.